# Backbone.js error - Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'set'

Tags: backbone.js

My Code:

I am new to Backbone.js and trying to build an app with Backbone.js and PHP. When I am trying to call `add` in the router, I am getting error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'set'.

Please help me to find my mistake.

Thanks.

```
    // Models
    window.Users = Backbone.Model.extend({
        urlRoot:"./bb-api/users",
        defaults:{
            "id":null,
            "name":"",
            "email":"",
            "designation":""
        }
    });

    window.UsersCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model:Users,
        url:"./bb-api/users"
    });


    // Views


    window.AddUserView = Backbone.View.extend({

        template:_.template($('#new-user-tpl').html()),

        initialize:function(){
            this.model.bind("click", this.render, this);
        },

        render:function(){
            $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
            return this;
        },

        events:{
            "click .add":"saveUser"
        },

        saveUser:function(){ alert('saveUser');
            this.model.set({
                name:$("#name").val(),
                email:$("#email").val(),
                designation:$("#designation").val()
            });

            if(this.model.isNew()){
                this.model.create(this.model);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });


    // Router
    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

        routes:{
            "":"welcome",
            "users":"list",
            "users/:id":"userDetails",
            "add":"addUser"
        },


        addUser:function(){ 
            this.addUserModel = new UsersCollection();
            this.addUserView = new AddUserView({model:this.addUserModel});
            $('#content').html(this.addUserView.render().el);
        }


    });

    var app = new AppRouter();
    Backbone.history.start();
```

Comment: Your passing a collection to the view and then trying to treat it as an instance of the model. It's not. It's a collection.

Comment: To clarify: the `Backbone.Collection` does not have a metod `set`.

Comment: If you're using a collection, you should `new View({ collection: ... })` instead of `new View({ model: ... })` and `this.collection` inside the view instead of `this.model`. That should prevent some confusion.

Comment: Hi @jakee sorry to bring up old thread but can you confirm your comment? [I see it here](http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/#Collection-set)

Comment: @Lim `Backbone.Collection` didn't get a `set` method until version 1.0.0.  Nag apparently was using an earlier version.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, the problem starts here here:

```
this.addUserModel = new UsersCollection();
this.addUserView = new AddUserView({model:this.addUserModel});
```

and finishes here:

```
saveUser:function(){ alert('saveUser');
    this.model.set({
```

By passing a collection in place of a model you create confusion, and as a result later in the `saveUser` function you try to call a `Backbone.Model` method (`set`) on a `Backbone.Collection` instance.

---

Note: As of version 1.0.0 `Backbone.Collection` now has a `set` method.  In previous versions, such as the one used by the question's author, that method was instead  called `update`.

---

There are several steps you can take to clarify this code.  For starters, I would rename your model and collection classes so that it's clear that the model is the *singular* form and the collection is the *plural* form:

`window.Users` => `window.User`

`window.UsersCollection` => `window.Users`

Next, I would create a new `User` model, instead of a `Users` collection, and pass that to your view:

```
this.addUserModel = new User();
this.addUserView = new AddUserView({model:this.addUserModel});
```

Finally, I'd remove these lines:

```
if(this.model.isNew()){
    this.model.create(this.model);
}
```

For one thing, the model will always be new (as you just created it before passing it in), but more importantly you don't need to call the `Collection`'s `create` method because that method creates a new model, when you already have one created.  Perhaps what you should add instead is :

```
this.model.save();
```

if your intent is to save the model to your server.

Since you already specified a `urlRoot` for the model, that should be all you need to create a new model, pass it to your view, have your view fill in its attributes based on DOM elements, and finally save that model's attributes to your server.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are facing problem with object scope. When event fired it send to event object to that function. Just try this it may work
Declare global variable with the current view  inside the initialize

```
initialize : function(){ self = this; }
```

then change this to self,

```
       saveUser:function(){ alert('saveUser');
        self.model.set({
            name:$("#name").val(),
            email:$("#email").val(),
            designation:$("#designation").val()
        });

        if(self.model.isNew()){
            self.model.create(this.model);
        }
        return false;
    }
```